# Oracle SQL: Conditionally update a table based on comparison with a SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (TABLE1) which has 4 columns:

**UID | PID | VALUE1 | VALUE2**

I have another SQL statement (STMT) which returns 3 columns from some other tables:

**UID | PID | VALUE1**

Now here are the condition of how I want to update TABLE1:

First, compare UID and PID pair from STMT with those in TABLE1,

1. for all new UID and PID pair not in TABLE1, insert new row from STMT into TABLE1, set TABLE1.VALUE2 = 0 (I've already done this one)
2. for existing UID and PID pair in both STMT and TABLE1, do:

   a. if TABLE1.VALUE2 > 0, update TABLE1.VALUE1 = STMT.VALUE1

   b. if TABLE1.VALUE2 = 0 and if TABLE1.VALUE1 != STMT.VALUE1, update TABLE1.VALUE1 = STMT.VALUE1, otherwise do nothing.

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for condition 2. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The end result after step 2 is that all cases of table1.value1 = stmt.value 1.  Do you specifically need to avoid updating rows to the same values they already are so that triggers don't fire?

Comment: @evilotto it's fine, the ultimate purpose is to make TABLE1 always up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT table1.UID
           ,table1.PID
           ,table1.value1 AS table1_value1
           ,table1.value2 AS table1_value2
           ,stmt.value1 AS stmt_value1
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ? AS UID
                       ,? AS PID
                       ,? AS value1
                FROM whatever) stmt
        ON stmt.UID = table1.UID
        AND stmt.PID = table1.PID
) x
SET x.table1_VALUE1 = CASE WHEN (x.table1_VALUE2 > 0) OR
                              (x.table1_VALUE2 = 0 AND x.table1_VALUE1 <> x.stmt_VALUE1)
                              THEN x.stmt_VALUE1
                         ELSE x.table1_VALUE1 
                    END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer cade, however i have a question that might be stupid: how do you cast sql statement into STMT so you can use it as STMT.value1 in your update statement?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm now getting "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" error. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: @AlanHan Just Oracle being difficult.  I could be as simple as just adding table1.UID and table1.PID to the x subquery to get the keys.  Otherwise refactor the query to remove the inner subquery by combining it or use a MERGE INTO technique instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 T
USING STMT S
ON (T.UID  = S.UID AND T.PID = S.PID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
T.VALUE1 = CASE WHEN T.VALUE2 > 0 OR (T.VALUE2 = 0 AND T.VALUE1 <> S.VALUE1) THEN S.VALUE1 END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT INTO T (COLUMNS) (SELECT COLUMNS FROM S);
```